# Как сделать ввод текста на С#

Tags: c#

Я написал код на С#

```
using System;

namespace Neosart_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Neosart OS";
            string name;
            Console.WriteLine("A:/Neosart>"); name = Console.ReadLine();
            //string neo = "A:/Neosart>";
            //Console.WriteLine(neo);
            //Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
A:/Neosart>
_
```

A как сделать так что было

```
A:/Neosart>_
```

Comment: Console.Write("A:/Neosart>");

Comment: `Console.Write("A:/Neosart>");` [Вот ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.15.php) - почитайте обязательно.